# Why are my angular-bootstrap tabs not rendering?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

Here is the site where you can view my angular app and also view source on it: http://clearsoftinc.com/dist/

There should be three blue tabs on the screen. I'm using the tabs directive from the ui-bootstrap directive for tabs (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). I used to have it working and now for some reason its broken. I have tried for two days to fix it, with no luck.

I have also posted a zip of the source code here:  http://www.clearsoftinc.com/Archive.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `controller.js`, change

```
angular.module('clearsoftDemoApp', [])
```

to

```
angular.module('clearsoftDemoApp')
```

If 2nd parameter of `module()` is presented, it defines a new application instead of getting the existing one defined in `app.js`.